# Multiple map functions and returning HTML

Tags: reactjs

I'm running into issues with multiple map functions and displaying data.  I believe I'm missing some returns in the appropriate spots, but can't find a good example online.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
Object.keys(patternData).map((pattern) => {
    if (patternData[pattern]['Matches'] && Object.keys(patternData[pattern] ['Matches']).length !== 0) {  
        Object.keys(patternData[pattern]['Matches']).map((matchSymbol) =>
            <p> {matchSymbol} </p>
        )
    }
})
```

Comment: The inner `Object.keys` on the 3rd line should be `return Object.keys // ..etc`. The reason it needs it is because the first line `Object.keys(patternData).map((pattern) => {` end in `{` which means the contents are not automatically returned like they are with `.map((matchSymbol) =>` which doesn't open the curly braces.